# Getting a 403 Forbidden error when I try to log in on the Wordpress iOS app

Tags: ios, wordpress

I'm using Automattic's iOS app for Wordpress and I'm trying to log-in for the first time to my site. I clicked the "add self-hosted site" option and put in the username, password and my self-hosted wordpress blog, and when I try to sign in I get a 403 error spit back at me.

Any ideas?

Comment: 403 that site does not exist! check your www.something.tla entry.

Comment: have you checked the network connection? Or is it possible that your IP is forbidden by this site?

Comment: If you're still trying to solve this, please list the plugins you have installed. This can be caused by a security/firewall plugin configuration.